# printing restaurant opening hours from a database table in human readable format using php

Tags: php, sql, database, time

i have a table that lists the opening hours of restaurants. the columns are id, eateries_id, day_of_week, start_time, and end_time. each eatery is represented in the table multiple times because there is a separate entry for each day. see this previous question for more details:
[determine if a restaurant is open now (like yelp does) using database, php, js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070295/determine-if-a-restaurant-is-open-now-like-yelp-does-using-database-php-js)

i'm wondering now how to take the data from this table and print it out in a human readable format. for example, instead of saying "M 1-3, T 1-3, W 1-3, Th 1-3, F 1-8" i would like to say "M-Th 1-3, F 1-8". similarly, i want "M 1-3, 5-8" instead of "M 1-3, M 5-8". how might i do this without a brute force method of numerous if statements?

thanks.

Comment: Is "m 1-3" how it's stored in the db? or is it a timestamp?

Comment: This is an interesting problem ... I will try to think about it. It does remind me a bit of circuit simplifications, which involves Karnaugh maps :) I assume that you care about high-level approach and can handle answers which do not match your exact table. By the way, are only whole hours allowed? When is the earliest possible hour and the latest possible hour?

Comment: I would start by having a hash table which maps a day to the hours, such as `{'M' : set(1,2,3,5,6,7,8), 'T' : set(1,2,3)}` or `{'M' : 'yyynyyyy'}` (indicating whether each hour (here starting at 1)) is available. This is the first step to determining which 2 days have the same schedule, as well as computing and simplifying the union of hours open. Why do all hours in your example start with 1? Is it a late restaurant? Do you care about 24h format? Do you want AM as well as PM in there? Are half-hour increments allowed?

Comment: to answer the questions: the times are stored in TIME format like 12:34:05. the days are in a separate column stored as integers (for example 2 represents monday). any time to the second is allowed, though i'm 99.9% sure that no restaurant's opening times will involve seconds :). the earliest hour is 00:00:00 and the latest is 23:59:59, so it's in 24h format. when i print the times for the user, i would like to use am/pm, though this conversion shouldn't be difficult once i figure the rest out. a high-level approach is fine, i just had no idea where to even begin with this problem!

Comment: MySQL. that's what you're asking, right?

Comment: @vee Yes. I don't think it supports the approach I was thinking of.

Answer (score 3):

Thought I would have a bash at this.

Test Table

```
CREATE TABLE `opening_hours` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `eateries_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_of_week` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Test Data

```
INSERT INTO `test`.`opening_hours`
(
`eateries_id`,
`day_of_week`,
`start_time`,
`end_time`)
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 1 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '15:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 1 AS day_of_week, '17:00' AS start_time, '20:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 2 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '15:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 2 AS day_of_week, '17:00' AS start_time, '20:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 3 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '15:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 4 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '20:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 5 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '15:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 6 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '20:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 2 AS eateries_id, 7 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '21:00' as end_time
                                                                       union all
SELECT 3 AS eateries_id, 1 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '15:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 3 AS eateries_id, 2 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '15:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 3 AS eateries_id, 3 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '15:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 3 AS eateries_id, 4 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '20:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 3 AS eateries_id, 5 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '15:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 3 AS eateries_id, 6 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '20:00' as end_time union all
SELECT 3 AS eateries_id, 7 AS day_of_week, '13:00' AS start_time, '21:00'  as end_time
```

View definition to consolidate opening hours by day

```
CREATE VIEW `test`.`groupedhours` 
AS 
  select `test`.`opening_hours`.`eateries_id` AS `eateries_id`,
         `test`.`opening_hours`.`day_of_week` AS `day_of_week`,
         group_concat(concat(date_format(`test`.`opening_hours`.`start_time`,'%l'),' - ',date_format(`test`.`opening_hours`.`end_time`,'%l %p')) order by `test`.`opening_hours`.`start_time` ASC separator ', ') AS `OpeningHours` 
         from `test`.`opening_hours` 
         group by `test`.`opening_hours`.`eateries_id`,`test`.`opening_hours`.`day_of_week`
```

Query to find the 'islands' of contiguous days with the same opening hours (based on one by Itzik Ben Gan)

```
SET @rownum = NULL;
SET @rownum2 = NULL;



SELECT S.eateries_id, 
concat(CASE WHEN 
S.day_of_week <> E.day_of_week 
    THEN 
    CONCAT(CASE S.day_of_week 
             WHEN 1 THEN 'Su'
             WHEN 2 THEN 'Mo'     
             WHEN 3 THEN 'Tu'     
             WHEN 4 THEN 'We'
             WHEN 5 THEN 'Th'    
             WHEN 6 THEN 'Fr'    
             WHEN 7 THEN 'Sa'  
            End, ' - ')
    ELSE ''        
END,
CASE E.day_of_week 
     WHEN 1 THEN 'Su'
     WHEN 2 THEN 'Mo'     
     WHEN 3 THEN 'Tu'     
     WHEN 4 THEN 'We'
     WHEN 5 THEN 'Th'    
     WHEN 6 THEN 'Fr'    
     WHEN 7 THEN 'Sa'  
End, ' ', S.OpeningHours) AS `Range`
FROM (

SELECT 
    A.day_of_week,
    @rownum := IFNULL(@rownum, 0) + 1  AS rownum,
    A.eateries_id,
    A.OpeningHours
FROM `test`.`groupedhours` as A
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `test`.`groupedhours` B
                 WHERE A.eateries_id = B.eateries_id
                  AND A.OpeningHours = B.OpeningHours
                  AND B.day_of_week = A.day_of_week -1) 
ORDER BY eateries_id,day_of_week) AS S

JOIN (
SELECT 
    A.day_of_week,
    @rownum2 := IFNULL(@rownum2, 0) + 1  AS rownum,
    A.eateries_id,
    A.OpeningHours
FROM `test`.`groupedhours` as A 
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM `test`.`groupedhours` B
                 WHERE A.eateries_id = B.eateries_id
                  AND A.OpeningHours = B.OpeningHours
                  AND B.day_of_week = A.day_of_week + 1)
ORDER BY eateries_id,day_of_week) AS E

ON  S.eateries_id = E.eateries_id AND
    S.OpeningHours = S.OpeningHours AND 
    S.rownum = E.rownum
```

Results

```
eateries_id             Range
2                Su - Mo 1 - 3 PM, 5 - 8 PM
2                Tu 1 - 3 PM
2                We 1 - 8 PM
2                Th 1 - 3 PM
2                Fr 1 - 8 PM
2                Sa 1 - 9 PM
3                Su - Tu 1 - 3 PM
3                We 1 - 8 PM
3                Th 1 - 3 PM
3                Fr 1 - 8 PM
3                Sa 1 - 9 PM
```

Comment: This is interesting. My opinion is that SQL should get you the data fast because that is what it is best at. The massaging of it is best done (I think) using a higher-level language. Your SQL is impressive though.

Answer (score 2):

You want to union a bunch of intervals for each day. Stick to 24h format (actually convert it to seconds first I guess) until you have to convert it to a human-friendlier format.

http://pyinterval.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/index.html

The trouble is that when you allow seconds ... a restaurant which closes 1 second earlier will be missed :( Perhaps you need to allow 15 or 5 -minute increments. Round the data in DB if you have to. So, the approach is: using an interval data structure, union all intervals for a given day together. Now reverse the dictionary. Instead of mapping days to intervals, map intervals to days. Now find a way to represent those groups of days intelligently. For instance, `set(1,2,3)` can be displayed as "M-W", so I would suggest: for every power set of the set `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` (or `{1,2,3,4,5}`) find the best human representation (by hand). Now hard-code this logic -save it into a dictionary which maps a ***sorted*** string (this is important) such as "1235" to a human representation such as "M-W,F". Displaying 1-3, 5-8 is easy, once you work with an interval object as is described in the link above. Good luck! Let me know what problems you run into.

***EDIT:***

This is not the best example that they have (does not show union of overlapping intervals), but you care about the "|" operator

```
unioned:

>>> interval[1, 4] | interval[2, 5]
interval([1.0, 5.0])

>>> interval[1, 2] | interval[4, 5]
interval([1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 5.0])
```

You could just implement this class yourself, but it might be prone to bugs.

Comment: Here I was assuming that Mon = 1, Tue = 2, ... Sun = 7 because this is a convention in some countries - the week starts on Monday and ends on Sunday. http://www.cjvlang.com/Dow/SunMon.html

Comment: i think i understand what you're saying.. though wouldn't there be over a hundred combinations of days that i'd have to hard code?

Comment: Not quite, 2^5 = 32; 2^7 = 128 :) These can be generated, however.